# Ускорение импорта данных

Tags: django

Импортирую данные из XLS (порядка 15000 строк) в БД Django

```
unit = Unit()
while sheet_ranges['D'+str(i)].value is not None:
    print "Raw number: ", i
    unit.bar_code = sheet_ranges['D' + str(i)].value
    unit.type = sheet_ranges['A' + str(i)].value
    unit.sn = sheet_ranges['C' + str(i)].value
    unit.desc = sheet_ranges['B' + str(i)].value
    unit.save()
    i = i + 1
```

Происходит это оооочень мееедленно, очевидно, из-за операции записи для каждой строки. 
Вопрос: можно ли это сделать одним выполнением метода модели save()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
units = []
for row in rows:
    unit = Unit()
    ...
    units.append(unit)
Unit.objects.bulk_create(units)
```